# Equal sign when implementing a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the meaning of "=" when you try to switch a pointer.

for example: `current->next = previous` and `current = previous`.

Comment: It's the same as it is for any other primitive value.

Comment: For the second assignment, you could say, "The _location_ `current` points to is now set to the _location_ `previous` points to."

Comment: Computer memory is a linear space that can be accessed through addresses. An address is an integer value. A pointer is an integer value that contains the address of a memory location. That's what every developer should know.

Comment: Great down-vote. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the second assignment, `current = previous`.  Here, the small boxes are the values of the pointers themselves, while the rectangles on the right are the things they *point to*.

Before assignment:

```
         +---+          +-----------+
current  | --|--------> | Obj1      |
         +---+          +-----------+

         +---+          +-----------+
previous | --|--------> | Obj2      |
         +---+          +-----------+
```

After assignment, both `current` and `previous` *point to* the object Obj2.

```
         +---+          +-----------+
current  | --|--+       | Obj1      |
         +---+  |       +-----------+
                |
         +---+  +-----> +-----------+
previous | --|--------> | Obj2      |
         +---+          +-----------+
```

Important takeaways:

- For an ordinary, raw pointer, the original Obj1 that `current` used to point to is unchanged.  It is not "deleted" or destructed by virtue of the assignment.
- Indeed, the assignment modifies *neither `Obj1` nor `Obj2`* themselves.
- If you change Obj2 (say, using `*current = func()`), then its changed state will be reflected when you access (read) it through *either* `current` or `previous`.
- It is very important to remember that pointers store *memory addresses*, and memory addresses are just numbers. So, when you assign a pointer to another, you're just putting a new number (i.e. address) in there.